# Generated Dart Editor web app not working

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I just downloaded the latest version of the dart editor and did the following:

1)  Created a new web application.  When I try to run, I get the following error:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)  
> http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/DartApps/HelloWeb/web/packages/browser/dart.js
```

2)  After some research, I tried the following - thinking I may need some dependencies - Pub install.  Now I get the following error:

```
> Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies... Got socket error
> trying to find package "browser" at https://pub.dartlang.org. OS
> Error: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized., errno = -8179
```

Any ideas what I can do to get past this issue?  I'm not getting very far.

Thanks,

Shon

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Both "Up and Running" and the pirate badge sample say nothing about pub-anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the pub update command first. That should update your dependencies.

http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-update.html

Comment: I get the same problem - "Peer's certificate issue is not recognized" error.